# Searching on multiple strings

Tags: c#, linq, search, lambda

I am having some issues with doing a search. I am trying to find a customer on either Name+Lastname, reference or CompanyName. I managed to get it working, however the the ordering is not 100%.

Here is my original object

```
var q = from row in DataAccess.metadata.db_Customer
        where row.accountID == accountID
        && row.isActive
        orderby row.Name
        select new bl_customerNames
        {
            customerID = row.customerID,
            CustomerName = row.Name + " " + row.LastName,
            Company = row.Company,
            Reference = row.reference,
            Email = row.Email,
            CurrencyCode = row.CurrencyCode,
            isSuspended = row.isSuspended
        };
```

Then I did the following filter.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
{
    q = q.Where(x => (x.CustomerName.Contains(search) || x.Reference.Contains(search) || x.Company.Contains(search)));
}
```

Although this does a fair job the list does not really make logical sense as its does not favor starts with above Contains.

I then came up with a ranking solution where I would rank Starts with higher than Contains.

Here is my code for that:

```
var q = from row in DataAccess.metadata.db_Customer
        where row.accountID == accountID
        && row.isActive
        orderby row.Name
        select new bl_customerNames
        {
            customerID = row.customerID,
            CustomerName = row.Name + " " + row.LastName,
            Company = row.Company,
            Reference = row.reference,
            Email = row.Email,
            CurrencyCode = row.CurrencyCode,
            isSuspended = row.isSuspended,
            Rank = ((row.Name + " " + row.LastName).StartsWith(search) || row.reference.StartsWith(search) || row.Company.StartsWith(search)) ? 1 : ((row.Name + " " + row.LastName).Contains(search) || row.reference.Contains(search) || row.Company.Contains(search)) ? 2 : 0
        };
```

I would then filter like this:

```
q = q.Where(r=>r.Rank > 0).OrderBy(r => r.Rank);
```

However if I search on reference it does not return anything.

So My question is will my current method work also why does nothing return if I search on reference or Company Name? What would the correct way of doing a StartsWith then Contains and still keeping some kind of alphabetical ordering after StartsWith List.

Please keep in mind I am still a junior developer and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I have amended my question.

Comment: try putting the filtering and ordering in the original query OR calling `ToList()` on it before applying filtering (just a hunch)

Comment: The Issue with that is, I can't materialise as it is a massive db and I need to do the filtering before hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to the basics and this is what I came up with.

```
           //Get customers that starts with
            var qSW = from row in DataAccess.metadata.db_Customer
                      where row.accountID == accountID
                      && row.isActive                         
                      where (row.Name + " " + row.LastName).StartsWith(search)
                      || row.Company.StartsWith(search)
                      || row.reference.StartsWith(search)
                      select new bl_customerNames
                      {
                          customerID = row.customerID,
                          CustomerName = row.Name + " " + row.LastName,
                          Company = row.Company,
                          Reference = row.reference,
                          Email = row.Email,
                          CurrencyCode = row.CurrencyCode,
                          isSuspended = row.isSuspended

                      };

            //Order
            qSW = qSW.OrderBy(r => r.CustomerName).ThenBy(r => r.Company).ThenBy(r => r.Reference);

            //Get customers that contains
            var qC = from row in DataAccess.metadata.db_Customer
                      where row.accountID == accountID
                      && row.isActive

                      where (row.Name + " " + row.LastName).Contains(search)
                      || row.Company.Contains(search)
                      || row.reference.Contains(search)
                      select new bl_customerNames
                      {
                          customerID = row.customerID,
                          CustomerName = row.Name + " " + row.LastName,
                          Company = row.Company,
                          Reference = row.reference,
                          Email = row.Email,
                          CurrencyCode = row.CurrencyCode,
                          isSuspended = row.isSuspended                            
                      };

            //If search is less then 3 chars limit to 10 to help with performance
            if(search.Count() > 2)
                qC = qC.OrderBy(r => r.CustomerName).ThenBy(r => r.Company).ThenBy(r => r.Reference);
            else
                qC = qC.OrderBy(r => r.CustomerName).ThenBy(r => r.Company).ThenBy(r => r.Reference).Take(10);

            //Concat list leaving out duplicates
            var SList = qSW.Concat(qC);


            // Return List
            return SList.ToList();
```

It seems to be doing the job and performance seems very good.